plantuml, how to avoid text or other objects overlapping?
I try to make nice picture with plantuml and 1 component inside another with some internal and external interfaces. Output is ugly with overlapping object and text in my example.
@startuml
left to right direction
component "component2" {
  portin " " as pi1
  portin " " as pi2
  portout " " as po1
  rectangle comp1
  pi1 --> comp1 
  pi2 --> comp1 
  comp1 --> po1
}

label "Interface1" as I1
label "Interface2" as I2
label "Interface3" as O3

I1 --> pi1
I2 --> pi2
po1 --> O3
@enduml

Output is:


I was reading about the ranking of nodes at https://isgb.otago.ac.nz/infosci/mark.george/Wiki/wiki/PlantUML%20GraphViz%20Layout and I will post a better solution. https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/ROwn3eCm34HtVuMLFKF2MY5Mfdv32eP62WaApbJrtuj3XLHHiTozCtVfDdQPon8WqCJ82REVduoZppImJn5WICkQ8aL6TKghy0M8Qyhi8whzSnkktlvXvijIuHCcWJBWuXm8fLR8VeowFInMRtzy5KAau0qGt8C2gZuovSaDP6jxRo-1EG9p2PeQt1i0sRhfekLtUSUX3UnJg7KhDnt5iIpX0m00

By trying to change the ranking of the elements using strategies from https://isgb.otago.ac.nz/infosci/mark.george/Wiki/wiki/PlantUML%20GraphViz%20Layout, I came up with:
@startuml
left to right direction

component "component2" {
  portin " " as pi2
  portin " " as pi1
  portout " " as po1
  rectangle comp1
  pi1 -> comp1 
  pi2 -> comp1 
  comp1 -> po1
}

label "Interface2" as I2
label "Interface1" as I1
label "Interface3" as O3

pi2 <-u- I2
pi1 <-u- I1
po1 --> O3
@enduml


